# Google map API find places by word

Tags: google-maps

I bought google API and I have the key

I want find places by words

As example I want search `carwash` and API return to me list of `carwashes`

I have this url but not work and return only one place

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={?!}&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: The geocoder returns postal addresses, not **places**.  Use the Places API.

Comment: @geocodezip I use this url but return one result : `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=carwash&inputtype=textquery&key={KEY}&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry&fields=formatted_address,name,geometry`

Comment: findplacefromtext literally returns ONE place. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests, if you want multiple places use nearbysearch https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have that result in your request is because you are not querying an address and your query is ambuiguous. Geocoding is designed to find a match on your input text that is why, it is suggested that you use the correct and properly formatted address in your input text otherwise it will return an unexpected result.

You need to use Places API's Place Search to search for place information using a variety of categories, including establishments, prominent points of interest, and geographic locations.

I can see that in your comment, you used [FindPlace](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) to search for it and you are saying that it only returns one result. This is working as intended as Find Place is intended to be used for a navigational search only which has a clear intent to find a single place.

As for your query, you can search for places either by proximity [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) or a text string [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests).

When you use the following code to query carwash in text search, you can have multiple results:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=carwash&key=YOUR_API_KEY`